# Logo wont change Magento 2.1.3

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3, logo

What i have done:

> - Fresh install of Magento 2.1.3
> - [Github] firegento-magesetup2; firegento/firegento-magesetup2
> - [Github] german language files; splendidinternet/Magento2_German_LocalePack_de_DE

My question is:
When i change the logo under content - configuration - edit (single shop configuration) - header
nothing changes in the frontend.

Any suggestion for this issue?

Comment: Did you clear Magento Cache?

Answer (score 2):

Step to change logo:

1. Go to Content->Configuration and click on EDIT (desired store)
2. Go to 'Header' under "Other Settings" section of page.
3. Upload the logo in this.

I added image for reference. Please check if it helps you. [image]

**Update:**
You can also do adding logo image in theme/default.xml file. Upload logo image in images directory of your theme and specify name in default.xml file.

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/logo_new.png</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">300</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">300</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Here you can also define height and width. *Images* directory path YOUR_THEME/web/

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what i did in the admin panel.

Comment: But i found out that no edits under "other settings" take effect to the frontend. Of course with clearing the cache. In my installation i dont have any folders under /app/design/frontend/Magento/. All theme files are located in vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/. Can this be the reason why all my settings are not applied? I also tried magento setup:static-content:deploy. No success...

Comment: [1] Under 'Other setting' you will to click on header to view this setting. [2] If you are not using custom theme then there will be nothing  under /app/design/frontend and only Magento directory, that's default. [3] No this is not reason and you are editing core theme files of luma theme vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/. You need to extend these files. Editing core files are not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

For all who have the same problem:
It does not work in single shop mode and i couldnt solve it (Magento 2.1.3).
After adding a new store and a new storeview the settings have been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to head down to your logo.phtml file for some edits:
In my case i found the file at /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/ThemeMaker/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml

or just look for logo.phtml (ubuntu : locate -i logo.phtml)

just change this:

```
 <center><img style="width:215px; height:57px;" src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLogoSrc() ?>"
             alt="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></center>
```

you can edit this code to look like :

```
<center><img style="width:215px; height:57px;" src="your-logo.png" alt="logos-Alt" /></center>
```

Comment: This is magento not static html. Dont do like that